# XmlEnum Multiple name for a single value

Tags: c#, xml, enums

I have this scenario, declaring a enum type. Like this:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "urn:un:unece:uncefact:codelist:specification:5639:1988")]
public enum LanguageCodeContentType {
    /// <summary>
    /// Afar
    /// </summary>
    [XmlEnum(Name = "AA")]
    AA,
    /// <summary>
    /// Abkhazian
    /// </summary>
    [XmlEnum(Name = "AB")]
    AB,
    /// <summary>
    /// Afrikaans
    /// </summary>
    [XmlEnum(Name = "AF")]
    AF,
    [...]
}
```

Now what I need is declaring multiple name for each value of the enum. Something like this

```
[Serializable]
[XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "urn:un:unece:uncefact:codelist:specification:5639:1988")]
public enum LanguageCodeContentType {
    /// <summary>
    /// Afar
    /// </summary>
    [XmlEnum(Name = "AA"),XmlEnum(Name = "aa")]
    AA,
    /// <summary>
    /// Abkhazian
    /// </summary>
    [XmlEnum(Name = "AB", XmlEnum(Name = "bb"))]
    AB,
    /// <summary>
    /// Afrikaans
    /// </summary>
    [XmlEnum(Name = "AF"), XmlEnum(Name = "af")]
    AF,
    [...]
}
```

Comment: You need to declare multiple `XmlEnum` attributes (which is not possible) or you need to be able to parse either `AA` or `aa` to `AA`?

Comment: How can I make this specific parse?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: It would help if you could explain why you need both upper- and lower case

Answer (score 0):

It's been a will, but I came along to this issue today.

I solved this by introducing multiple entries in my enumeration.

```
public enum LanguageCodeContentType {
    AA = 0,
    aa = 0,
    AB = 1,
    ab = 1,
    AF = 2,
    af = 2,
    [...]
}
```

By this ether, "aa" or "AA" could be serialized.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).